# Exclude Sent Emails from Gmail filtering and labelling system

Tags: filter, gmail, label

I am using gmail Label to create different section in my Inbox. Problem is that all sent email that has that same subject gets into my labeled section on the inbox. Is there anyway of excluding the Sent email and label only in incoming emails?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-from:me` to your filter?

Comment: Looks that you are applying the label to threads instead of messages. Please add more details to be sure about what you are doing (if you still have the problem).

Answer (score 8):

Try this please:

```
in:inbox from:(-me)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use exclamation mark to make clause negative

```
!label:sent
```